# Jquery - How to execute a a function only when ajax request is complete and all content is alread loaded

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I have this 2 functions to be execute but I want the second to be executed only when the content of the first request is already loaded in the DOM element..

general function that loads ajax content:

```
function ajaxDialog(AjaxUrl, type, targedDom, dialogedDom, tabs) {

$.ajax({
    url: AjaxUrl,
    type: type,
    DataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        //puts data inside targedDom Dom elemen
        $('#' + targedDom).html(data);
        //create tabs
        loadDialogSettings(dialogedDom, tabs);
    }
});
```

}

this first function creates a tab sctructure:

```
ajaxDialog('/Admin/AdminSettingsTabsStructure', 'POST', renewedDom, targetDom, true);
```

and this one populate with some content tab number 2

```
loadRolesAndAcessRules('/Admin/AdminRolesAndAccessRules', 'GET', 'tabs-2');
```

I was thinking in execute the second function on the onComplete callback from the Ajax request but is a little confusing... could I get some help?

Thanks

Comment: That looks like what you would do. What isn't working?

Comment: Why don't you execute loadRolesAndAcessRules function in the success callback?

Comment: DigitalD: You where right. This worked perfectly and it is very fast too. The thing is that this lots of code lines was puzzling my mind. 12 hours in front of a computer programming some times just beat you down! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
function ajaxCallReturning(AjaxUrl, type, targetDom, tabIndex) {

$.ajax({
    url: AjaxUrl,
    type: type,
    DataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#' + targetDom).html(data);
    },
    complete: function () {
        if (tabIndex == "1") {
            $("#tabs .ui-tabs-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
            $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: tabIndex })
        } else {                
        }
    }
});
```

}

As you can see, All the data is loaded into the DOM inside of a success callback and after the loading is complete, the complete callback function is called and display the tab with the data.

Thanks a lot!